# change part of the screen javaFX

Tags: java, spring, javafx

so Basically I an working on this project car registration and I find difficulties in changing part of the page so I used the boarder pane to and I reached a point that I can change the middle pane but to null I believe that the problem comes from here

This is my code:

```
private Pane view;

@FXML
public Pane getPage(String fileName) {
    try {
        URL fileUrl = App.class.getResource("/org.example/" + fileName + ".fxml");
        if (fileUrl == null) {
            throw new java.io.FileNotFoundException("FXML file can't be found");
        }
        view = new FXMLLoader().load(fileUrl);
    } catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("No page " + fileName + " please check FxmlLoader.");
    }
    return view;
}
```

This is where I believe the problem comes from:

```
URL fileUrl = App.class.getResource("/org.example/" + fileName + ".fxml");
```

because I get (No page addingACar.fxml please check FxmlLoader.
)

my question is I am not sure how to reach the file I assigned as a URL

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: beware: your resource lookup is brittle - don't mix back-slashes with periods

Comment: @kleopatra *"don't mix back-slashes with periods"* I saw two forward slashes, no back slashes. Aside: I was just preparing to write this before your comment. **`/org.example/` should probably be `/org/example/`.**

Comment: @AndrewThompson *hehe - well spotted, meant forward slashes ;)

Comment: But even when I get the file I have a problem with this: view =new FXMLLoader().load(fileUrl); it causes an exception

Comment: In addition to the advice of @kleopatra. *"it causes an exception"* As programmers, we see a lot of them: 1) Always copy/paste error and exception output! The stack trace allows to see exactly where in a MRE the problem occurs. 2) See [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788/418556) & [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/218384/418556)